# image upload/edit is broken: "Image data does not exist. Please re-upload the image."

Tags: images, uploads

Image uploads (slowly), and displays in the media window.

But size shows "**(0 × 0)**" and if I try to use *Edit Image* button I can't edit the image but instead get this message:

***"Image data does not exist. Please re-upload the image."***

I have 2 different WP installs each with unique plugins, and the problem exists on both installs

*Is it WP 3.1 recent upgrade? Is it a plugin? Other?*

Comment: Usually this happens when you upload very large images, due to PHP timing out. Try uploading an image with a small image size and see if that works. If so, you'll have to up the PHP memory limit in .htaccess or wp-config.

Comment: OK, if I waited 30 more minutes I could have avoided this post... I solved it...

The problem was the WP Smush.it` plugin. Deactivate this plugin and all works well.

I had already increased my memory limits, and the file size was only about 200k.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if I waited 90 more minutes I could have avoided this post... I solved it...

The problem was the `**WP Smush.it**` plugin. Deactivate this plugin and all works well.

I've had problems with this plugin before in different ways...very finnicky.

I had already increased my memory limits, and the file size was only about 200k. That wasn't my particular issue.

Comment: Interesting. I've used WP-SmushIT on several different sites and have never had a single problem with it.

Comment: I haven't ever had issue with the plugin either. What host are you using? In case that's the cause.